# RStudio, updating packages, restarting R, RStudio goes into endless loop

Tags: r, windows-10, rstudio, updating

My script gives me a message that I have version 0.2.5 of tidyselect and that version 1.1.0 is required.  I use RStudio to update tidyselect.  RStudio gives me the message that Restating prior to updating is strongly recommended and that RStudio can restart R and then automatically continue the installation.  When I click yes, RStudio goes into an endless loop, continually producing this same message abut updating Loaded Packages.

I don't see any other way to update this package, and this method using RStudio also does not work.

I have the latest (as of today 9/30/20) versions of RStudio and R.

Comment: can you try to close the Rstudio application completely, reopen it, and run `install.packages("tidyselect")` in the console before anything else ?

Comment: Can you choose not to restart `Rstudio` and observe that the package will be updated?

Comment: Both comments are helpful.  First I deleted the package, shutdown RStudio, and restarted fresh. Not sure why, but it is working now.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There could be multiple problems at hand but I can think of some that might occur as they have done with me as well.

`install.packages("remotes")`

#would be aid to install the package into R, then fill in the code below.

`remotes::install_github("r-lib/tidyselect")`

Since tidyselect is connected to several other packages, R studio will request you to update the other packages as well.
If your packages are not updated, it might go into a loop.

Enter `1` after the request to update here to update all the connected packages.

I hope this helped. Otherwise rephrasing your question would help me give more clarity to the situation.